# Use of docker files in GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to use pandoc to generate pdfs from Markdown files in a Github Action. For this purpose, I intended to use an existing Docker container to improve performance. But unfortunately, I could not simply switch between a native `ubuntu-latest` and `pandoc/latex:2.9` by adding a corresponding container reference (deleting the `#` in line 6). In this case, I received an unexpected error message that did not occur without the pandoc container.

```
name: Execute_pandoc
on: [push]

jobs:
  Run_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    #container: pandoc/latex:2.16

    steps:
      - name: Illustrate the problem
        run: |
             echo "Hello World"
             dirlist=(`ls *`)
```

```
Run echo "Hello World"
Hello World
/__w/_temp/2ac5de2c-2847-4b00-8a97-ba3bb034898e.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected "("
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Comment: It would make sense to use an action for that. You can either create your own custom action based on that docker image or try and find an existing one on marketplace. I see there's already one there: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pandoc-document-converter

Comment: Ok, probably it's more effective. But why does the example not work in both cases? Do I have to handle concrete containers differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax error you're getting is because shell doesn't understand your command. Try setting different shell or change command.

Keep in mind that base image for `pandoc/latex` in your example is `alpine` which uses `ash`. You could simply use another pandoc image that's based on some other distro.

Here's an example:

```
name: Execute_pandoc
on: [push]

jobs:
  Run_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: pandoc/ubuntu-latex
    steps:
      - name: Illustrate the problem
        run: |
             echo "Hello World"
             dirlist=(`ls /*`)
             echo ${dirlist[@]}
        shell: bash
```